# Welcome comment deleted

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

I looked at other similar questions before posting this and couldn't find a close fit.

I welcomed a new user to Stack Overflow being aware of making the site more user friendly. I added a "welcome to Stack Overflow" comment under their question and answered the question to boot.

The new user replied thanking me also in a comment. Why has my comment disappeared from the question? I didn't get any notifications. Has it been deleted? As it reads the new user comment in reply is there still.

[Here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63383620/pygame-doesnt-exit-when-run-through-cmd/63383769#63383769)

Comment: Mods generally don't delete comments that contain useful information, but there are cases where a comment containing certain words/phrases can get automatically deleted by flags (I'm not sure if that applied here so hopefully someone with more insight can answer). That said, if your comment had information that answered the question, it really ought to go in an actual answer (unless the question was close-worthy, in which case it isn't much of a loss considering the OP already saw it).

Comment: Why not link the question? Then we can see exactly what may have happened.

Comment: @10 Rep question link added

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood what you were saying. What was the text of your comment exactly?

Comment: Yes it was just "welcome to stack overflow" and looking at the Q again after the user replied I said something like "enjoy the adventure", that too is missing. Sorry can't remember exact wording.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Without seeing the full text of your comment it's hard to be sure, but it was likely flagged as No Longer Needed and removed (either by the system or by a moderator):

[image: This comment is outdated, conversational, or not relevant to the post.]

Take a look at [the Help Center page about commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

#### When should I comment?

> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the
>   question has been updated).

Comments should contain substantive information. Friendly chit-chat like "Welcome" and "Thanks" does not fall into any of these categories, so **comments should not be used for that purpose**.  It's true that there has been a push to make the site more inclusive, but the idea is leave friendly **and helpful** comments that guide new users towards improving their questions and finding answers, rather than just saying hello without any substance.

Stack Overflow has been always been *very* strict about minimizing chit-chat and cutting straight to substantive discussion -- to the extent that greetings and salutations [are routinely removed from posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950). Our goal is to build a library of high-quality programming Q&A, and any off-topic noise adds clutter and reduces the usefulness of the site, especially to future visitors who came from Google and just want to get a quick answer instead of reading through pages and pages of back-and-forth dialog.

Comment: that makes sense as "welcome to stack overflow" is certainly conversational

Comment: The motivation behind making the site more friendly and inclusive is to avoid *snarky* comments, not to litter the site with fluff. Stick to the point; keep things technical and on-topic. Omit conversation about users and your opinions about them or their technical skills.